# NSMutableArray to NSString to UIImageView CODE CRASHES

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Any idea why my code would crash? I am taking an `NSMutableArray` converting it to an `NSString` and using the string to get the URL for my `UIImageView`. Crashes at `NSURL` Line.

```
NSString *imgstring = [imageOne componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: At a minimum you should include the *exact* and *complete* exception message and the exception stack trace, plus the relevant code.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg9ub3xlj2j5afx/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-02%20at%2011.03.35%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: check the ' imgstring' is nil or not . Please post the error message also.

Comment: @user2868511 , strange your code perfectly working at my end, Can you let us know what exception you are getting

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Documentation,

URLString: The URL string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808.

In OS X v10.7 and later or iOS 5 and later, this method returns nil if the URL string is nil. In earlier versions, this method throws an exception if the URL string is nil.

Comment: It is coming out nil. How do I fix this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg9ub3xlj2j5afx/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-02%20at%2011.03.35%20PM.png?dl=0